# While storing the user's data in cloud, which convension should we follow whether 1KB = 1024 bytes or 1000 bytes?

Tags: web-applications, size, standards, filesize, conventions

What is the standard method to calculate file size?

The hard devices they follow the convention that 1KB equals 1000 bytes but in computer science we have learnt that 1 KB equals 1024  bytes.

So, while storing data in cloud which convention should we follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has already been settled with the use of [Binary Prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix).

Unless you are selling HDD it is generally understood that *1KB = 1024 Bytes*.

Both Linux and Windows, with their respective commands and interfaces, show file sizes using that convention so that's what the user is most accustomed to.
Furthermore it also doesn't mix units up when comparing with memory and bandwidth.

The clearest solution however would be to explicitly use the binary prefixes like *KiB*, *MiB*, and so on.